# OpenSSL installed but no openssl.pc (needed by pkg-config)

Tags: pkg-config

Can .pc files be generated if they aren't installed? I have installed OpenSSL but there is no 'openssl.pc' on my computer.

Any suggestions?

Comment: OK I needed to install libssl-dev. Why is finding out the names of packages always some trial and error? (I tried a.o. libopenssl-dev...) Anyway this problem is solved. (BTW: I wanted to mark this question as solved but I don't know how)

Answer (score 11):

You need to install the package `libssl-dev`.

You can use "Search the contents of packages" on https://packages.ubuntu.com/ to search for a package that contains a given file.